# Como evitar o bloqueio por quantidade de acessos no Facebook Graph?

Tags: facebook

Tenho uma rotina para consulta dos últimos 50 posts:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?limit=10', function(response) {
    var friend_data = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
        FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT post_id, source_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = ' + friend_data[i].id + ' LIMIT 50'
            },
            function(posts){
                console.log(posts);
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

Ela funciona perfeitamente, até que recebo esta mensagem de erro:

```
"error_code":"613"
"error_msg":"Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds."
```

Evidentemente, existe um bloqueio de quantidade de consultas, limitadas a 600 requisições a cada 6 minutos. Pode ser que eu não esteja fazendo as contas corretamente, mas esta rotina gera 1 requisição para buscar os 10 amigos e outras 10 requisições de stream, certo?

Existe algo que possa ser feito para contornar este problema?

Comment: Tem algum motivo para fazer mais de uma requisição por segundo em uma página?

Comment: 600 requisições a cada 10 minutos. 600 segundos = 10 minutos.

Comment: O contexto em que sua query ultrapassa o limite de requisições é essencial para o problema, por favor esclareça.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para aumentar o entendimento.

Comment: @AlexandreBonfá Ainda não fica claro o problema. São 11 requisições, e como o Facebook te identifica baseado no IP + TOKEN, isso deveria funcionar para todos seus usuários. Se o problema é o usuário atualizar a lista muito frequentemente, então você deveria fazer a requisição no backend e controlar com banco de dados quando você deve trazer a informação do banco e quando você deve fazer uma nova requisição depois de X minutos passados depois da última.

Answer (score 2):

Você está fazendo esta requisição para milhares de posts diferentes?

Existem três maneiras:

1. otimizar suas queries para aproveitar ao máximo cada requisição, por exemplo utilizando a instrução `IN ()`.
2. colocar um timer que controla a quantidade de requisições de modo que você não ultrapasse o limite.
3. o Facebook identifica aquele que faz a requisição utilizando o par token e IP. Isto quer dizer que duas aplicações (que utilizam o mesmo ip) podem fazer o dobro de requisições. Você poderia por exemplo criar alguns aplicativos para resolver o problema do limite, mas isto só é escalável até certo ponto.

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua aplicação está fazendo mais que 600 requisições a cada 6 minutos (ou seja, 1.66~ requisições por segundo) tem provavelmente algo de muito errado com a forma que você está estruturando a sua aplicação.

Pôr o bloco do seu código que faz as consultas dentro de uma função `setInterval` com intervalos de um segundo já seria suficiente para evitar exceder a quantidade máxima de transações, mas caso seja realmente necessário o Facebook fornece [uma página](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) onde você pode negociar um número maior de acessos por dia.